# Is "besides, I think you already know" a correct translation of "なにせもう覚えったようなもんだから"?

Tags: translation, meaning

なにせもう覚えったようなもんだから = "Besides, I think you already know"?

Also, is 覚えった a misspelling of 覚えた?

Comment: We never say 覚えった.  Probably a typo for 覚えた.

Answer (score 1):

Without any context, we could not say that is the correct translation but it is obviously one of the possible translations.

Without context, we just do not know who it is that has mastered something.